# CrashLoopBackOff for Kubernetes pod

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a client that needs to send requests to a server on the port 5000. I want to deploy this application in k8s and I got the following error in the client pod:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='server-service', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fab6a560730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='server-service', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7
```

The client deployment file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client
        image: client:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
```

The server deployment file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server
        image: server:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: server
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
```

The scope of the application is to send http requests to a server to simulate a denial of service attack. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: I want to mention that k8s server node is up and running successfully.

Comment: Assuming both Deployments are to the same Namespace, `server-service` is on port `80` (the container port is 5000 and the service's `targetPort` is correctly 5000 too).  You should confirm this by attempting to connect to the `Service` probably easiest using `kubectl port-forward service/server-service 8888:80` and then, from that same host, using `localhost:8888` to try to connect. `8888` because you generally can't bind to `80` without sudo.

Comment: Aside: it's common but I feel an anti-pattern to name Kubernetes resources by their Kind, i.e. `server-service` and `client-deployment`. Kubernetes Resource names are unique by Kind and so you can have a `Deployment` called `foo` and a `Service` (that exposes it) called `foo` too.

Answer (score 0):

`I have a client that needs to send requests to a server on the port 5000.`

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: server-service
spec:
selector:
app: server
ports:

- protocol: TCP
  port: 80
  targetPort: 5000`

Assuming both client and sever application are in same namespace.

Solution:
`server-service` is configured to expose port `80`(not port `5000`). So, please update the client application to connect to `server-service` in port 80.

Answer (score 0):

`I have a client that needs to send requests to a server on the port 5000.`

Assuming both client and server application are in the same namespace.

Solution:
`server-service` is configured to expose port `80`(not port `5000`). So, please update the client application to connect to `server-service` in port 80.

Answer (score 0):

As other said your server-service on port 80

so your client has to call server-service with port 80

HTTPConnectionPool(host='server-service', *port=5000 -> 80*)

and also consider about your server is working on host `0.0.0.0`

Sometimes in python (flask server for example)
The server application should be configured to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0).
If the server is bound only to a specific host address, such as localhost or 127.0.0.1, it may not accept external connections.